# Convergence result of GD when $κ \leq \frac 12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, convergence-divergence, convex-optimization

I have the following theorem in my lecture notes of optimization on a Euclidean space $E$ :

Let $f : E → \Bbb R$ be $µ$-strongly convex and have $L$-Lipschitz
continuous gradient. Define $κ =\frac Lµ$
. Let $x^∗$
be the (unique) global minimizer of $f$. Given an arbitrary $x_0 \in E$, gradient descent with constant step-size $1/L$, that is, $x_{k+1} = x_k − \frac 1L ∇f(x_k)$ produces a sequence $(x_k)$ which satisfies
$$f(x_k) − f(x^∗) ≤
\bigg( 1 − \frac 1κ \bigg)^k
(f(x_0) − f(x^∗
))$$
that is, $f(x_k)$ converges at least linearly to the optimal value $f(x
^∗
)$.

I don't really see why does the sequence $f(x_k)$ converge if $κ \leq \frac 12$ because $\bigg( 1 − \frac 1κ \bigg)^k$ will diverge right ? So was the condition $κ \leq \frac 12$ forgotten or I am misunderstanding something (maybe the case $κ \leq \frac 12$ does not happen ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, we always have $L \geq \mu$ so the case I described never happens